# SSRS Deadlock Save Parameters Error

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report which saves the users parameters.
There is a query that looks like the following:

```
USE Database
EXEC Database.SP

@UserID
,@Report
,@Parameter
,@Value
,@Save
,@FilterSetName
```

For some reports, this query is used multiple times to save different parameters which might be on a report (Department, Status, Age). I have started getting the following error:

"Transaction (Process ID 131) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."

I understand this to be because there are 2 queries trying to execute a stored procedure which inserts and updates various tables. SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED and with (nolock).

I am have tried applying these to my query (possibly incorrectly) and the error persists.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
UPDATE Database.Table
SET Table.Object  = '0' 
WHERE Table.Object = @UserID
```

Any advice?

Comment: `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` has no impact on inserts, it only allows dirty reads.

Comment: I see. Is there a similar way to handle this situation for insert/update statements?